# update UIProgressView with keyValueObserver not working

Tags: swift, xcode, key-value-observing, uiprogressview

I want to show the progress while zipping some files with ZIPFoundation.
The zip method can take a `Progress` object and continuously updates the `fractionCompleted` value for that object.
I can access the `progress` value with the `observeValue(forKeyPath)` method but the `UIProgressView` is not updated continously. The UI is updated after zipping is finished.
Setting `progressView.progress` value directly or via `DispatchQueue.main.async` makes no difference.

Any idea where my bug is?

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) { 
    if keyPath == "fractionCompleted" {
       let progress = object as! Progress
        let progressFloat = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.progressView.progress = progressFloat
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: How did you set up (update) Progress? Did you try to print `progressFloat` in above callback, is it really progressing from 0 to 1? And... is self.progressView present, not nil?

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it was a thread problem: I did the zipping on the main thread which was blocking my whole UI. By putting the zip Function in the background with **DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { zipThis }** everything works fine.